# Move UIView Programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, frame

My app displays banner ads at the bottom of the screen.

Above these ads are several UIViews/UIImageViews etc.

If the user removes the ads, via IAP, there is an empty gap where the banner used to be, as expected.

However, I would like to move these views down vertically, so as to reduce the obvious gap in the screen.

The code I've been trying doesn't seem to be working -

```
    UIView *moveView = [self.view viewWithTag:5];
    CGRect frame = moveView.frame;

    [moveView removeFromSuperview];

    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 25.0;
    moveView.frame = frame;

    [self.view addSubview:moveView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below suggested to remove autolayout, however I needed autolayout for my storyboard.

I simply needed to remove the autolayout for one UIView.

What I ended up using was

```
[moveView settranslatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints:YES]
```

This simple line allowed me to move my view around without worrying about autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IBOutlet and connect it to a UIView in storyboard.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *moveView;
```

then turn off auto layout in your storyboard.

[image]

Once that is done then try your code.

or try this

```
[moveView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
```

Comment: I've answered my question above. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

mmmbaileys is right.!!

Small Change:

```
[self.yourview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

use this in viewDidLoad.

Comment: please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift you content quality up